# getDao exception with generatedId = true

Tags: java, android, auto-increment, ormlite

I want to insert record to my sqlite database without providing ids for new record. All ids should be autogenerated.

So, id column is defined as:

```
//primary key
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = C_ID,generatedId = true)
private int cID;
```

But there is exception thrown while getting dao:

> Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify one of id,
>   generatedId, and generatedIdSequence with cID
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify one of id, generatedId, and generatedIdSequence with cID
>               at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.(FieldType.java:201)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:153)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:72)
>               at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:279)

I don't really understand how to fix this? Exception throws here:

```
public Dao<Countries, Integer> getCountryDao()
    {
        if (null == countryDao)
        {
            try
            {
                countryDao = getDao(Countries.class); <---Exception
            }
            catch (java.sql.SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return countryDao;
    }
}
```

This works:

```
//primary key
    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = C_ID)
    private int cID;
```

Bu I need to provide ID when inserting new records. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this

```
 @DatabaseField(columnName = C_ID,generatedId = true)
 private int cID;
```

Comment: not Exactly my answer but I found my problem with this. VERY IMPORTANT POINT: can't use field "int id" with "@DatabaseField(id = true)". must write something like this: "@DatabaseField(columnName = "myID" , id = true)".

Comment: Can you explain why it should be like this?

Answer (score 4):

`id` and `generatedId` do not work together. Use

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true)
```

with your column name.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm usually in a situation similar to yours I use:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = COUNTRY_SEQUENCE_DEF)
  @SequenceGenerator(name=COUNTRY_SEQUENCE_DEF, sequenceName = COUNTRY_SEQUENCE_DB , allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
  private Long cID;
```

These annotation should do the trick in your case.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are correct.
However i just wanted to point out that the error description is worded quite poorly.

It says
`Must specify one of id, generatedId, and generatedIdSequence with cID`
which means you can only one *ONE*. They are all exclusive options.

So you **either** use *id* **or** use *generatedId* **or** use *generatedIdSequence*

(I made the same assumption as you and thought that i wanted an id column that is also a generatedId)